# Voltage on undefined GPIO pin

Tags: gpio, voltage

If I do not specify the output of GPIO pin (like GPIO.output(4, False)),
I always have a voltage of 1.3V  on this pin

How can I set all pins to 0v? and why are undefined pins have this voltage of 1.3v???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default state of pins is given in http://www.panu.it/raspberry/

The default Device Tree settings configure most pins as inputs, some with pullup others with pulldown.

Pins set as input cannot be said to "have a voltage", except for the high value pullup resistors they are in a high impedance state. Any voltage you measure is a artefact, and depends as much on the measurement circuit as the state of the pin.

If you want to change the pullup on a input pin you would do something like `GPIO.setup(4, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)`

Incidentally **DO NOT** use constructs like `GPIO.output(4, False)` - You are **NOT** setting the pin to False, use `0` or `1` (or constants like `GPIO.HIGH`) which will make your code easier for you, and others, to read.

Answer (score 0):

With the pin defaulting to be an input, and with no pullup/pulldown defined you are just looking at the (relatively undefined) high-impedence voltage of the input pin.